# What is $_SESSION and how do i secure SESSION name in PHP

Tags: php, session

my SESSION starts after sucessesfull login and i really don't know how safe is my SESSION value

My SESSION value is `user name` and here is my code

```
<?php
require_once('includes/config.php');
if ($user->is_logged_in()) {
    header('Location: signup.php');
}
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $username = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username');
    $password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password');
    if ($user->login($username, $password)) {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        header('Location: index.php');
        exit;
    } else {
        $error[] = 'Wrong username or password or your account has not been activated.';
    }
}
?>
```

Here is my function

```
private function get_user_hash($username){  
        try {
            $stmt = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT password FROM members WHERE username = :username AND active="Yes" ');
            $stmt->execute(array('username' => $username));
            $row = $stmt->fetch();
            return $row['password'];
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
        }
    }
    public function login($username,$password){
        $hashed = $this->get_user_hash($username);
        if($this->password_verify($password,$hashed) == 1){
            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
            return true;
        }   
    }
```

Now i need to know how safe is my `$_SESSION`

and how do i secure my $_SESSION value

Comment: Encrypt the session data?

Comment: but in some Question i read encrypt doesn't make any sense, and it of no use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it is valuable to have a deeper understanding of how sessions work in PHP. When you run `session_start()`, PHP registers an ID for the current visitor and allows you to start storing/receiving information linked to the session ID, for example:

```
session_start(); // Registered visitor ID on server "B3D4IUC86"
$_SESSION['password'] = "test1234"; // Stores password for visitor "B3D4IUC86"
echo $_SESSION['password']; // Retrieves 'password' index for visitor "B3D4IUC86"
```

It is best practice not to store secure/unencrypted data directly on the user's machine as this data can be intercepted in transfer or accessed directly. Rather, store an ID which you can lookup on your machine(s) and find the information internally. This will also (slightly) increase network transfer speeds as you are not transferring all data, but only a simple ID which you can lookup.

Comment: what if i just store `user name`

Comment: Storing the username is fine for sessions as long as you are able to look up this value in some sort of database system (MySQL, NoSQL, MongoDB etc)!

Comment: some sort of database system means what ..?

Comment: In your code there is a line where you make a query (`$stmt = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT password FROM members WHERE`...). It appears that you are querying an existing database. I personally recommend making a new table and storing session information, but you can continue to do it your way as this is still acceptable (and valid) practice. If you are unsure of your ability to maintain/edit a table, contact a DB administrator for help!

Comment: so i need to create a new table for storing only session values, and that table should contain only session names  (`username`)

Comment: if the usernames are already stored somewhere in the database, there is no need to store them again. If you need to get information about the user, you will use `$_SESSION['username']` to retrieve the value, then query the database with the user information to get information about users with that username

Comment: my table consist of `username, password(hashed and salted) active, email`